# Как можно реализовать аналог функции kbhit() в linux?

Tags: c++, linux

В программе на С++ под linux нужно проверять, нажата ли любая клавиша. В windows это делает функция kbhit() из библиотеки conio.h, которой в linux нет. Подскажите, как можно реализовать аналог такой функции, или может такая функция есть, только иначе называется?

Comment: select или poll не подойдут?

Comment: См. первый ответ [тут](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/kbhit-34027/). Приведена реализация kbhit, требуется библиотека ncurses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int _kbhit() {
    static bool inited = false;
    int left;

    if (!inited) {
        termios t;
        tcgetattr(0, &t);
        t.c_lflag &= ~ICANON;
        tcsetattr(0, TCSANOW, &t);
        setbuf(stdin, NULL);
        inited = true;
    }

    ioctl(0, FIONREAD, &left);

    return left;
}
```

Comment: Видимо не совсем так. [Здесь](http://www.codenet.ru/progr/cpp/spr/264.php) описание kbhit.

Очевидно, что делать setbuf(stdin, NULL); и менять (не восстанавливая) режим потока **это неправильное решение**.

Надо смотреть, есть ли символы в буфере потока (см. /usr/include/libio.h struct _IO_FILE) и если пусто ioctl(0, FIONREAD, &left);

Answer (score 0):

это копия
/**  Linux (POSIX) implementation of _kbhit().
 Morgan McGuire, morgan@cs.brown.edu  */

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/select.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <stropts.h>

int _kbhit() {
static const int STDIN = 0;
static bool initialized = false;

if (! initialized) {
    // Use termios to turn off line buffering
    termios term;
    tcgetattr(STDIN, &term);
    term.c_lflag &= ~ICANON;
    tcsetattr(STDIN, TCSANOW, &term);
    setbuf(stdin, NULL);
    initialized = true;
}

int bytesWaiting;
ioctl(STDIN, FIONREAD, &bytesWaiting);
return bytesWaiting;
}

//////////////////////////////////////////////
//    Simple demo of _kbhit()

#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
printf("Press any key");
while (! _kbhit()) {
    printf(".");
    fflush(stdout);
    usleep(1000);
}
printf("\nDone.\n");

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Неправильный код. См. комментарий к предыдущему (от @stanislav) ответу.